# Point multiple paths to the same - URL Rewriting

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I developed a webapp and now I want to implement the same webapp to another client. The maintenance becomes complicated with different paths: domain.com/client1 and domain.com/client2 using the same webapp.

So, my idea is to use URL Rewriting in order to use the same webapp. eg.
domain.com/client1 and domain.com/client2 using same webapp domain.com/webapplication, and using database client1 and client2 respectively.

By getting the URL path, I already identify on my php code the correct database. I did many tests on my .htaccess without success.
Is it possible to do this? If so, can someone give me an idea or suggesstion? I don't want to use subdomains for other reasons.
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** Database usage is done. Just missing my URL Rewriting.

Comment: Try rewriting from the url base `/` off. This would require an .htaccess file in your domain root, which calls an index.php routing the client'sto your webapplication and setting corresponding variables like the database name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So interesting, someone else asked almost the same but some hours before. Anyway, part of his explanation helped me to solve my problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33915314/use-htaccess-to-redirect-several-urls-to-one-folder

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^name_1/(.*) store/$1
```

**The only thing is that I have to create every path (folder) for my clients, empty of course.** Definitely I was missing that.

Answer (score 0):

A .htaccess with this contents might help:

```
AcceptPathInfo On
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?p=/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Then it would be possible to get the path with $_GET['p'] in index.php (placed both in the document root).

Your index.php could just look like this:

```
if(preg_match($_GET['p'], "/^client1/")) {
    $database = "client1";
} elseif(preg_match($_GET['p'], "/^client2/")) {
    $database = "client2";
}
require_once 'webapplication/app.php';
```

But you could alos use something like [Alto Router](https://github.com/dannyvankooten/AltoRouter).